# TXC 9C-11.2896MAAJ-T XTAL Type

Tags: avr, atmega, crystal

For the purposes of configuring an ATmega324A for use with an XTAL, is the TXC 9C-11.2896MAAJ-T considered to be a low power crystal oscillator or a full swing crystal oscillator?

Please see page 39 of the ATmega324A [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega164A_PA-324A_PA-644A_PA-1284_P_Data-Sheet-40002070A.pdf).

Thanks.

Comment: Please read next couple of datasheet pages as it has the answer. Which part is unclear?

Comment: I don't see how the data sheet species the type of crystal oscillator that the TXC 9C-11.2896MAAJ-T is. Maybe you can clarify.

Comment: You seem to have asked a question about two components (ATmega + TXC), but have only provided a datasheet for one. Can you add the missing datasheet and explain where in the mode selection process the ATmega datasheet has confused you?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the AVR datasheet, it says you can use either low power mode or full swing mode with a crystal of that frequency, but only if the AVR supply voltage is high enough. If supply voltage is too low, you can't use full swing mode then.

Comment: But it says nothing about the particular crystal I picked. Certain settings must be changed in the MCU, depending on what type of crystal is used. I can't seem to find the classification of the crystal I've chosen.

Comment: It is not a classification of the crystal, it is a classification in which mode the oscillator inside AVR is set to.

Answer (score 0):

I have normally used the full-swing setting but it is not critical.

The main issue is whether you are using the XTAL2 output for driving other devices (either another MPU or logic).

See page 42:

> "This Crystal Oscillator is a full swing oscillator, with rail-to-rail
>   swing on the XTAL2 output. This is useful for driving other clock
>   inputs and in noisy environments."